# A possible bug in reviewing close vote

Tags: support, review, review-audit

I was reviewing some close vote recently and come to this one:

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/348342

The particular question is not important. The main point is that I wanted to leave a comment, I found out that it didn't work. Then I chose to leave it open and wished to go back to the original question. Then (I kind of expect that) it shows that it is an audit.

It seems that (normally) one can leave a comment when reviewing vote. Should that be considered a bug?

Comment: [Some more or less related things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+comment+review+audit). It used to be that clicking "add comment" instantly failed the audit, if I understand correctly. At least some audits. That seems to have been changed. I don't know whether it is supposed to let you write a comment but not actually post the comment when you click/press return, or not to let you write the comment at all.

Comment: It's as @DanielFischer says. Comments only look like they are working (they don't actually get posted) - we know those posts are good/bad, commenting on them doesn't help at all.